# C# Entity Framework generates a table column not in my model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I used code first and Entity Framework to generate my databases. I defined a class called `CRUDModel` when I first set this process up.

When I ran the code, a new model was created called `CRUDModel.edmx` and under that there are two models called `Contact` and `EmailAddress`.

This is the contents of `Contact.cs`:

```
public partial class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }    
    public virtual EmailAddress EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the contents of `EmailAddress.cs`:

```
public partial class EmailAddress
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public EmailAddress()
    {
        this.Contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress1 { get; set; }
    public int EmailType { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the application, the database gets dropped and recreated.  The results of running the application is the creation of 2 tables, `dbo.Contacts` and `dbo.EmailAddresses`.

Also, under the `CRUDModel.edmx` is a file called `CRUDModel.Context.cs`. This is the contents of this file:

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities()
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

I have to assume that when Entity Framework creates the database, it names the tables based on the `DbSet` definitions.

When I expand the 2 tables (`Contact` and `EmailAddresses`) in a database they look like this

Contact Table

- ID (PK, int, notnull)
- FirstName (nvarchar(max), null)
- LastName (nvarchar(max), null)
- EmailAddress_ID (FK, int, null)

EmailAddresses Table

- ID (PK, int, notnull)
- EmailAddress1 (nvarchar(max), null)
- EmailType (int, not null)

When I seed the `Contacts` and `EmailAddress` tables, or when I add data to the two tables, the value that gets placed into `dbo.Contacts.EmailAddress_ID` is equal to `dbo.EmailAddresses.ID`.  This is correct.

Now, I would like to read from the tables. I would like to execute a JOIN by executing the following code:

```
using (var Context = new ContactContext())
{
    List<Contact> contactsList = Context.Contact.ToList();
    List<EmailAddress> emailAddressesList = Context.EmailAddress.ToList();

    var contactRecord = (from c in contactsList  // get the Contacts table
                         join e in emailAddressesList  // implement the join on the emailaddresses table
                              on c.EmailAddress_ID equals e.ID
                         select new ContactPassData
                                 {
                                     passedID = e.ID,
                                     passedfName = c.FirstName,
                                     passedlName = c.LastName,
                                     passedeMail = e.EmailAddress1,
                                     passedeMailType = e.EmailType
                                 });
    return View(contactRecord);
}
```

The problem is that there is no `EmailAddress_ID` anywhere in my models so there's no way for me to join the tables.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the correct approach using EF. You don't load the entity lists then use Linq against the collections. EF supports Linq and builds queries using the relationships defined in your entities via navigation properties..  Instead, your query should be:

```
var contactRecord = Context.Contacts
    .Where(c => c.Id == contactId)
    .Select(c => new ContactPassData
    {
        passedID = c.ID,
        passedfName = c.FirstName,
        passedlName = c.LastName,
        passedeMail = c.EmailAddress.EmailAddress1,
        passedeMailType = c.EmailAddress.EmailType
    }).Single();
```

This assumes based on your call you would want to load a single Contact. If you want all Contacts, remove the `Where()` condition and replace `Single` with `ToList`. I.e.

```
var contactRecords = Context.Contacts
    .Select(c => new ContactPassData
    {
        passedID = c.ID,
        passedfName = c.FirstName,
        passedlName = c.LastName,
        passedeMail = c.EmailAddress.EmailAddress1,
        passedeMailType = c.EmailAddress.EmailType
    }).ToList();
```

This will have EF build a query that loads just the requested fields from one contact and it's related email address rather than loading ***all*** contacts and email addressess and all of their columns.

Edit:

When using navigation properties, EF will employ conventions to set up FKs automatically. For instance, if I have an entity structure:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual EmailAddress EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

public class EmailAddress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

When EF sets up the relationship between contact and EmailAddress, it will look to see if Contact has a field that looks like the FK, so it will check for EmailAddressId, or EmailAddress_ID, etc. and it will use those if found. If it doesn't find one, it will attempt to use a shadow property with it's default naming convention, so EmailAddress_ID is added to your table.

What is important about this is if you have something like:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual EmailAddress EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

You might expect for the CreatedBy User reference EF would use something like CreatedBy_ID, but it will actually use User_ID as the naming convention is based on the Type of the property, not the property name. Even if you declare a FK property:

```
public int CreatedById { get; set; }
public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

it still will expect a User_ID. If you have multiple properties of type User, you will get keys  like User_ID1, User_ID2, etc. which aren't very helpful for schema read-ability. To tell EF what FK to use:

```
public int CreatedById { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

This tells EF what to use for the FK. You might see examples with the `[ForeignKey]` attribute on the FK property pointing at the navigation property. This is fine as well. It either points to the FK, or on the FK pointing to what the FK is for.

If you don't want the FK exposed as a property on the entity (recommended) but want to control the name of the DB column then you need to set that shadow property up in the Entity configuration. (`OnModelCreating`, or using an `EntityTypeConfiguration`) The syntax will depend on the version of EF you are using.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation but I dont see how your solution executes a Join.  In your .Where, I think c.ID is a reference to the ID column of the Contacts table but I need to make use of the EmailAddress_ID column.  And where does your contactID come from? I dont have that as a table column or model element anywhere.

Comment: If your view is going to display a single contact (implied by "contactRecord") then how would you define which contact record to load? Otherwise if you want to view all contact records, remove the where clause and use ToList. The relationship for EmailAddress_ID is managed by EF entirely behind the scenes which is why that column was added to your table. You could have created an EmailAddress_ID or EmailAddressId property in your Contact entity and EF would have used that by convention. You could use another name like ContactEmailId but you would need to configure it to serve as the FK.